# Enque queries until express server is ready to respond

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express app that after it starts, an external data is fetched from an external source. Until data is fetched in the app, this will respond all the queries with a default template.

For the firsts 3 or 4 seconds, the app is responding with that template and then works normally.

This is an issue in fact. I want to avoid that default response. I want to check (after server is running) if the data is or not is fetched yet and then wait until correct response is ready to sent.

That is, despite the firsts seconds, client will feel that the app is slow, this will receive the correct response always.

Comment: Fix the server.

Comment: They're already "enqueued" until you call `res.end()` (or res.send/json/render). What's exactly stopping you from not sending the "default response" until whatever data is fetched?

Comment: data will be fetched on memory once and only in the beginning with an async method. That is, server is running without info required to response. If during the fetching (3-4 sec) any request coming the route will not resolve nothing and it'll go for a middleware to handle default errors with a default template. I want not to sync the data fetching. Instead, if a request is coming and not data is available then the request should wait until data is fetched and only then given a response

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this:

```
async function fun (req, res, next)  {
    while (!sitemap['/'] && Object.keys(sitemap).length == 0) {
        await new Promise(done => setTimeout(done, 20));
    }
    next();
}

app.use(fun);
```

I guess, it is a dummy solution but apparently works. I forced the fetch of data to require at least 10 seconds and using this function as middleware the client keep waiting until server finishes to load its data.

Maybe someone could tell me if it is fine or not.